# Admob reward video for the application which is not on playstore

Tags: android, admob, ads, rewardedvideoad

I want to display rewarded video ads in my android app. which i'm not going to upload on play store.

So can i use admob for displaying rewarded video ads.

If yes,

this is what i want to do
By viewing ad user will get some points, then after user will use that points for specific app purpose.

is this legal for google and admob, or i will face account suspension case.

Thank you

Comment: If you're not going to upload your app to Play, just use Rewarded Video *Test* Ads.

Comment: did you find an answer ? did rewarded videos are displayed inside your app which is not in google play store ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video go through this link you will get clear about it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually i know the process of integration and infect already done it and video ads is also displaying, I just want to know the way i m using the ad is legal in google's T&C prospective?